# I am trying to make a discord.js avatar command, and the mentioning portion doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have an avatar command in my discord bot. When the user uses `h.avatar`, it outputs their avatar, which works fine. Whenever they try to use `h.avatar @user`, nothing happens. 
Here is my code:

```js
 } if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "avatar")) {
      if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        const avatarAuthor = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0x333333)
      .setAuthor(message.author.username)
      .setImage(message.author.avatarURL)
        message.channel.send(avatarAuthor);
        let mention = message.mentions.members.first();
        const avatarMention = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x333333)
        .setAuthor(mention.user.username)
        .setImage(mention.user.avatarURL)
        message.channel.send(avatarMention);
```

Comment: This Questions still seems to be unresolved, could you please mark a Answer as accepted, or self answer if you have found the Solution? @cyliim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a check `if (!message.mentions.users.size) {` which makes the command run only if you do not mention somebody. You either need to use an `else {` in your code or do:

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + 'avatar')) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x333333)
        .setAuthor(user.username)
        .setImage(user.avatarURL);
    message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
}
```

The `const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;` tries to get the user that was mentioned but if it does not find anyone it will use the author's used.

This can also be used like this:

```
if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
    message.channel.send('Nobody was mentioned');
    return;
}
// continue command here, after guard clause
```

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing like `avatarUrl` unless you have defined it.
Use this code to get the url of a user:

```js
message.channel.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/"+message.author.id+"/"+message.author.avatar+".jpeg");
```

Just replace`message.author` with the user who is mentioned

Comment: There is. It used to be a property called `avatarUrl` but now it's a method called `displayAvatarURL()` https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL This question is from 2019 when `avatarUrl` was correct. Things have changed since then. You do not need to construct the URL yourself.

Answer (score 2):

These is the updated version of the answer that works

```
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + 'avatar')) {
const user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
const avatarEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(0x333333)
  .setAuthor(`${user.username}'s Avatar`)
  .setImage(
    `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.id}/${user.avatar}.png?size=256`
  );
msg.lineReply(avatarEmbed);
}
```

This uses discord's avatar url, and msg.lineReply(avatarEmbed); is a function that sends the embed as a reply to the message

Answer (score 1):

My

```
if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'avatar')) {
  const user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
  const avatarEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('')
    .setAuthor(`${user.username}'s Avatar`)
    .setImage(
      `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.id}/${user.avatar}.png?size=256`
    );
  msg.reply(avatarEmbed);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30149319)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+'av')){
    
        
        if(message.mentions.users.size){
            let member=message.mentions.users.first()
        if(member){
            const emb=new Discord.MessageEmbed().setImage(member.displayAvatarURL()).setTitle(member.username)
            message.channel.send(emb)
            
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send("Sorry none found with that name")

        }
        }else{
            const emb=new Discord.MessageEmbed().setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL()).setTitle(message.author.username)
            message.channel.send(emb)
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'avatar')) {
   let user = message.mentions.users.first();
   if(!user) user = message.author;
   let color = message.member.displayHexColor;
   if (color == '#000000') color = message.member.hoistRole.hexColor;
   const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                   .setImage(user.avatarURL)
                   .setColor(color)
    message.channel.send({embed});
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.