# Avatar command in discord.js not picking up mentions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

this thread did not solve my problem thats why im asking again. 
[I am trying to make a discord.js avatar command, and the mentioning portion doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55605593/i-am-trying-to-make-a-discord-js-avatar-command-and-the-mentioning-portion-does)

when i use my avatar command without mentioning the user it shows my avatar as intended but when i mention a user it says "undefined's avatar" and shows no avatar

```js
module.exports.run = async (Client, msg, args) => {
    let member = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.author

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${member.username}'s Avatar`)
    .setImage(member.avatarURL)
    .setColor(0x233f23);

    msg.channel.send(embed)

}
```

it looks like its not finding the mentioned user but i have no idea why

before i had used

```js
if (!member) member = msg.author
```

but that still gave me the same problem so i applied the fix from the thread i linked above and its still the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define member in `let member = msg.mentions.members.first()` you are working with the class `GuildMember`, when you define it through `let member = msg.author`, you are working with the class `User`. Be sure to check in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) what you are working with.

Now, when you get the member from the mention both `username` and `avatarURL` are null because those properties don't exist in the member class, as an example, to get a user's username, you would need to first go to the `user` property in `GuildMember` like this, `let username = member.user.username` you could alternatively get the member nickname, witch is a property that exists in `Member`.

After all of this, here's your code with the fixes I just described in mind:

```
module.exports.run = async (Client, msg, args) => {
    let member = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.member // Changed from msg.author so that we can work with the same class in both cases

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${member.user.username}'s Avatar`)
        .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)
        .setColor(0x233f23);

    msg.channel.send(embed)
}
```