# Fixing code for a discord !avatar command

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a bot that one of it's commands puts the image into the embed and so far only time it works is when I do !avatar but I would like it to be able to do !avatar @the specified user then it put that users profile picture link. This is the code that it currently has.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!embed')) {
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription(message.content)
        .setFooter('Cloudzy')
      message.channel.send({ embed })
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need the mention id for the user, from the message?

Comment: I am not quite sure right now this is what im stumped at.

Comment: The link that was posted a second ago I was able to catch not quite sure who posted it but I may have code that works so I will check with that one if mine doesn't work thank you though.

Comment: I posted the original link, which is the same as the one I used to link this as a duplicate question. The suggested answer should work for you.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl the other post worked thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that command with my bot and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is a sample bot that can issue a rich embed with a user's avatar.

All you have to do is send the following command to the server.

> `!avatar @username#0000`

#### Bot - index.js

```js
const config = require('./config.json');
const { token } = require('./auth.json');
const { Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const logger = require('winston');

const client = new Client();

// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, { colorize: true });
logger.level = 'debug';

client.on('ready', (evt) => {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ' + client.user.username + ' - (' + client.user.id + ')');
  });

  client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return; // Not listening...
    const withoutPrefix = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim();
    let args = withoutPrefix.split(/\s+/g);
    let command = args.shift();

    switch (command) {
        case 'avatar':
            // Credit: PLASMA chicken - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55611445/1762224
            const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
            const avatarEmbed = new RichEmbed()
                .setColor(0x333333)
                .setAuthor(user.username)
                .setImage(user.avatarURL);
            message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

#### Config - config.json

```
{
    "prefix" : "!",
    "inviteLink" : "<INVITE LINK HERE>"
}
```

#### Authorization - auth.json

```
{
    "token": "<AUTH TOKEN HERE>"
}
```

Comment: That is basically the same bot that I have just a few more commands and mine works great.